# Responsive html background splits the screen in certain proportion

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I want to set this background to my html webpage. This background splits the screen in two colors with one line that goes from upper right corner to one point of the horizontal bottom line. It does not split it from corner to corner. The thing is that I want to do it in a responsive way. For example, the line could start in the 25% of the bottom length to the top right corner. I all screens, without scroll bars. Something Like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEPrm.png)

I have tried this:

```
        body{
            width: 100%;
            height: 114vh;
            background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, white 50%, blue 50.1%);
            background-size: 100%;
            background-position: center center;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

But it is not responsive. Not in all screens the screen is split in the same way and some scrolls appear.

Comment: Do you want the body to be that size, or do you want the screen to have that background - and if so is it to be fixed so it's there even when the user scrolls or would it scroll as the user scrolls?

Comment: I want this background in the screen (no matter what size I choose) and I want all the content (text and images) to adapt to the screen in the same way. If I have got this split background with a title in the top and some text in the bottom (center) I want to keep that aesthetic, that proportion to all users in all screens.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer you question?

```
body{
        width: 100vw;    /* edited */
        height: 114vh;
        background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, white 50%, blue 50.1%);
        background-size: 100%;   /* can be removed */
        background-position: center center;   /* can be removed */
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden; /* added */
    }
```

Comment: Yes and no. Yes, that makes dissapear the scroll bars and it keeps the proportion of the split section. But I have got two problems now: 1. I don't want to hide the overflow. 2. The text and the content I added can be affected when different screens are used. Whatsmore, the bottom of the page is hide in smaller ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the background on a before pseudo element and use clip path to cut it to the right shape, using % offsets so it is responsive.

For example:

```html
<<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <style>
    body {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    body::before {
      content: '';
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background: blue;
      clip-path: polygon(25% 100%, 100% 0, 100% 100%);
    }
  </style>
  </head>

  <body></body>
```

It depends on whether you want the triangle to be fixed in the screen or not as to whether you position the pseudo element fixed or absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Don't play with body height, play with the `background-size`

```css
html {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, white 50%, blue 50.1%);
  background-size: 80% 100vh; /* 80% = 100% - 20% (your offset) */
  background-position: top right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```